# Do RabbitMq policies override queue parameters?

Tags: rabbitmq

### Problem

Our clients can create their own queues on the RabbitMq cluster and we need to control the important parameters on the queue (ttl, expiration etc.).
The issue is that we cannot be sure what value is actually applied: the one from `x-arguments` or the `policy`.

### Question

[In this rabbitmq documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html#operator-policy-conflicts), there is nicely explained how are different policies resolved but it does not mention the priority of `x-arguments`.

So if the queue is created with `x-message-ttl : 180000` and the applied policy defines `message-ttl : 100000`, like this :

[image: queue definition]

... what will be the applied value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer is likely Yes

It looks like **policies do override** the queue `x-attribute`.

#### Why ?

Well, it did for `max-length` in this small **test** (with ver 3.10.11) :

- Queue was created with `x-max-length: 5`
- Policy of `max-lenght: 3` applied
- Number of ready messages dropped from 5 to 3

[image: max_length_overriden_by_policy]

Comment: I think the answer is more nuanced. I did this same test with a `message-ttl` and `x-message-ttl`, and the _shorter_ of the two was taken. So the queue property is effectively a maximum value for the TTL.